# What is this variable declaration code doing?

Tags: javascript

I was browsing through the jade templating engine source code and I am trying to figure out what this statement means.

I get that it's going to try and instantiate `options.compiler` and if that fails instantiate `Compiler`, but the next part confuses me... Is this saying to call `parser.parse` and declare the returned value as a variable? If so, why is the rightmost paren around options?

```
var compiler = new (options.compiler || Compiler)(parser.parse(), options)
  , js = compiler.compile();
```

.
Here's some more context if that helps

```
function parse(str, options){
  try {
    // Parse
    var parser = new Parser(str, options.filename, options);

    // Compile
    var compiler = new (options.compiler || Compiler)(parser.parse(), options)
      , js = compiler.compile();
```

[Github - Line 960](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade.js#L960)

Comment: `new (options.compiler || Compiler)` must return a function that takes two parameters...

Comment: It's just the second argument for the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down.

```
(options.compiler || Compiler)
```

This expression seems to be designed to look for a "class" (well, technically a constructor function, this being JavaScript). The options object may be used to specify it, or else it will fall back to whatever is referenced by `Compiler`.

```
new (options.compiler || Compiler)(/* ... */)
```

Okay, now this makes more sense. We're invoking a constructor. It's just that the "class" was chosen dynamically.

```
new (options.compiler || Compiler)(parser.parse(), options)
```

When we income the constructor, we're passing in two parameters. The first is the result of calling the `parse` method of the `parser` object, and the second is the options object from earlier.

```
var compiler = new (options.compiler || Compiler)(parser.parse(), options)
```

That unholy mess is stored in the `compiler` variable.

```
var compiler = new (options.compiler || Compiler)(parser.parse(), options), js = compiler.compile();
```

You can declare and assign multiple variables in the same `var` statement, so that confuses things further. But the last part is pretty easy to understand by itself.

That statement could, and probably should, be broken down into multiple lines... but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

`var compiler = new (options.compiler || Compiler)` does not try to *instantiate* `options.compiler`. It looks for the *existence* of a `compiler` constructor as the property of `option`. If it doesn't find it, it uses `Compiler` as the constructor.

It then just passes those 2 arguments to the constructor being used: the first argument is the returned value of `parser.parse()`, and the second argument is `options`.

---

To simplify it, this can be rewritten as follows:

```
var theConstructor = options.compiler || Compiler;
var parsedStuff = parser.parse();
var compiler = new theConstructor(parsedStuff, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks funny because the constructor to call is itself an expression.

And no, it isn't quite computing `parser.parse()` as the value of the declared local `compiler,` but rather it's creating a new object from the one returned and *initializing* `compiler` from that.

And, that rightmost paren is just because the code is aware that whatever constructor is returned ... it's going to want two parameters.